# Rails 3 UJS: Passing in params when using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How to we pass in additional params besides the ID

```
#we want to pass in additional params as well
<%= link_to  "bleh", like_path(answer), :add_param=>2 , :remote=>"true" ,:method=>:post %>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can pass parameters in the path function as part of the url. Something like:

```
<%= link_to "bleh", 
  like_path(:answer_id => 123, :add_param => 2), 
  :remote=> true , :method=> :post %>

# would result in something like
# yourapp.com/like/aswer/3?add_param=2
```

But I think you need to move away from the purely resource based path helper in this case. Check the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) for ideas.

Answer (score 29):

If you don't want to put the parameters into the path helper - perhaps because there's a lot of them or you don't know them when the page is generated - you can also put them into the **`data-params`** attribute.

For example:

```ruby
link_to "Add to cart", cart_path, 
    data: { method: :post, remote: true, params: { product_id: 123 }.to_param }
```

The generated HTML looks like this:

```html
<a data-params="product_id=123" data-remote="true" data-method="post" 
    href="/cart" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>
```

The JQuery UJS handler attaches everything from the `data-params` attribute to the POST request body.

Conceptually there's not much difference to using the path helper in the first place, but if you want to modify the parameters in Javascript this solution might yield more elegant code.

Comment: Great answer ! I was looking for something like this. I knew Rails magician would have something for this too. Where did you find this ?

Comment: It is not documented (at least I found none) but it is in the code. Also it is a suprisingly simple statement, which provides that feature: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/commit/dad6982dc592686677e6845e681233c40d2ead27

Comment: This is great stuff. Good job! for finding and sharing.

Comment: This is great as it's difficult to figure out best syntax for `data-params`. I use ruby `.slim` files instead of HTML. And I've found using Rails' `button_to` helper the best way to make a fully functional UJS link: 

`= button_to "Press me", some_path, class: "button is-info", remote: true, params: {toggle: toggle}, data: {disable: {with: 'Loading...'}}`

p.s. please excuse the formatting above